# wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files, failed to run

Tags: wp-cron

[image]

The scheduled event, wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files, failed to run. Your site still works, but this may indicate that scheduling posts or automated updates may not work as intended.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Please add more details to your question; without context there is no answer possible.

Comment: I'm getting this error in Site Health Status, there is nothing more.

Comment: Site Health Status will tell you about ANY CRON job that fails to run... ...but what plugin is adding that CRON job.  Try adding the Action Scheduler plugin and go review what's in there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.